# Show/hide shape while running macro combined with screenupdating = false

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'd like to show a shape when my Excel is running a macro that refreshes several queries and adds some formulas and updates some pivots.

I'm able to display and hide the shape with the following code:

```vb
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 4").Visible = True
    DoEvents
    DoEvents

code

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 4").Visible = False
```

I however want to combine it with `screenupdating = false` once the shape is made visible.

If I add this to the code (after making the shape visible) it doesn't show the shape anymore. Does anybody know what I can do to show the shape but turn off screen updating during the remainder of the code?

Regards,
Léon

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Have you tried to show the shape before setting screenupdating to false?

Comment: Thanks. :) Yes, setting screenupdating to false is part of the 'code' part.